# How can I keep copying after a "NT_STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION" error with smbclient?

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer, smb, smbclient

I have a directory of files that need to be copied every night as a backup.

I am using 'smbclient' to backup the files to a Linux machine but I am seeing an issue where if a file is locked the entire copy process will abort with a NT_STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION error.

Is there any way to get smbclient to keep copying the rest of the files in the directory and gracefully skip over the locked files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `smbclient`. Mount the shared drive somewhere using `mount.cifs` and use `rsync` to make the backup. Example:

```
# mount.cifs //server/share /mnt/cifs
# rsync -a /mnt/cifs/directory ~/backups
```

This would mount the share to /mnt/cifs and then recursively copy `directory` to `~/backups/directory`.

Read up on the usage of [`rsync`](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/storage/8200-back-up-like-an-expert-with-rsync) since it is a powerful program and has a few gotchas.

Comment: I could be wrong but if the windows server has a lock on the file then wont the rsync behavior be the same as the smbclient?

Comment: From a [semi-official source](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2013-January/028037.html): "Rsync does
continue after it encounters a permission denied error." This should pertain to your case as well. As far as I have seen, `rsync` never quits on a read error for individual files.

Comment: What do you know, this worked like a charm. Sometimes its just about using the right tool for the job I guess. - The only thing i did different was use cygwin to get an rsync/ssh connection to the windows machine.